# How do add a custom transition delay between view controllers while using coordinators?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, coordinator-pattern

Most of the answers I found for transitioning between view controllers had to do with the normal pushViewController. I am using coordinators for my navigation so was wondering how I can add transition between my UITableView controller and the next transition controller:

Below is the code I am using to navigate between view controllers:

The coordinator:

```
class ItemsCoordinator: ItemsBaseCoordinator {
    
    func passData(i: Int) {
        let vc = Items2ViewController()
        vc.selectedIndex = i
        //resetToRoot(animated: false)
        navigationRootViewController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
```

First View Controller:

```
class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController, ItemsBaseCoordinated{
    
    var coordinator: ItemsBaseCoordinator?
    
    init(coordinator: ItemsBaseCoordinator) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        title = "Items"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
   
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        tableView.register(ItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
       
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        coordinator?.passData(i: indexPath.row)
        
        
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class Items2ViewController: UIViewController, ItemsBaseCoordinated {

var coordinator: ItemsBaseCoordinator?
    
    var itemList: [ItemInfo] = [ItemInfo(itemName: "HP Ink Cartridge", itemPrice: 50, itemStatus: "Published", itemImage: UIImage(named: "printer.jpeg")!), ItemInfo(itemName: "iPad",itemPrice: 600, itemStatus: "In Progress", itemImage: UIImage(named: "ipad.jpeg")!),ItemInfo(itemName: "Hoodie",itemPrice: 45, itemStatus: "Unpublished", itemImage: UIImage(named: "hoodie.jpeg")!)]
    

var items: ItemInfo!
var selectedIndex = 0

lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    
    
    let dl = UILabel()
    let a = itemList[selectedIndex].itemPrice
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Item Price:          $\(a)")
        string.setColorForText("Item Price:", with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.411764705882353, green: 0.411764705882353, blue: 0.411764705882353, alpha: 1))
        
    dl.attributedText = string
    dl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    return dl
}()
```

I am passing data between the view controllers using a protocol function, how do I add a transition delay between the screens?

Comment: What do you mean transition delay? Means that delay push view until something or go the second view and delay UI appearance?

Comment: I mean the transition that comes when you segue between screens when using pushViewController

Comment: "Most of the answers I found for transitioning between view controllers had to do with the normal pushViewController. I am using coordinators for my navigation" So what? You are still saying `pushViewController`, so the coordinator makes no difference. If, as you say, you know how to make a custom push transition animation, just make one.

Comment: "I am passing data between the view controllers using a protocol function" No, not really. It's an ordinary method of an ordinary class. The fact that the view controller refers to the coordinator by way of a protocol type is irrelevant.

Comment: So I have replaced pushviewcontrollers with coordinators (which I have omitted to reduce verbosity), but with coordinators the transition that you see when using pushviewcontroller is missing which is what I want to achieve

Answer (score -1):

I just had to set animation to true in the pushviewcontroller